# parse file in perl using awk commands

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I am trying to achieve something from below input file **input.txt**:

```
ron@xyz.com   8   10
ron@xyz.com   9  11
jack@abc.com  2   6
test@pqr.com  2   7
jack@abc.com  8   5
test@pqr.com  3   5
```

Now I want **op.txt** :

```
ron@xyz.com 38
jack@abc.com 21
test@pqr.com 17
```

Explanation:

1) Want one record (email) only once.

2) Want sum of column two + column three ($2+$3) for all the records of same email ids. 

e.g:

 file contains two entries of **ron@xyz.com**

```
  ron@xyz.com   8  10
  ron@xyz.com   9  11
```

so, sum of 1st line (8+10) plus second line (9+11) equals 38.

 If a shell script is more feasible then I can go with that. 

**EDITED:**

I did try following commands, but I don't know how to integrate both, since the first one finds the sum of specified key words:

```
cat input.txt | grep "ron@" | awk '{print $1+$2}'|paste -sd+ | bc
```

And this one finds unique entries for the first column:

```
cat input.txt |awk '{print $1}'|uniq
```

Comment: First, try it yourself and see what you come up with.  Then we can help you.  Second, I don't understand what "in perl with awk commands" means.

Comment: `(8+10) + (9+11)` is 38, not 28.  Expected value for jack@abc.com also looks wrong.

Comment: @F.J Sorry my mistake edited the question.

Comment: Edited Question with attempts i tried before posting question, sorry i didn't mentioned that early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '{
    a[$1]+=$2+$3
}
END {
    for (i in a)
        print i, a[i]
}' input.txt > op.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

if input.txt has more columns to be added, this command will be more useful.

awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) a[$1]+=$i}END{for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' infile